# Java Axis WebService Overload Control

Tags: java, controls, overloading, axis

We want to implement a overload mechanism on our axis Web Service. 
Basically we want to reject the incoming the SOAP requests when the TPS(Transactions Per Second) value reaches a specified value say 100 or 150.
To make this we need to count the number of requests received and the number of responses sent.

Could you please suggest me on where to start for this implementation? How to count the requests and responses?

Many Thanks,
Sekhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should implement the message counting and dropping in a handler. Here's a good description in the Axis documentation of how to write and register handlers in your web service: [Using handlers in JAX-WS Web services](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/jaxws-guide.html#Handlers).

Basically, what you do code-wise: You create a handler class implementing `javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler`. In the `handleMessage(...)` method, you count the incoming messages and, as the [Javadoc for the Handler interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/Handler.html#handleMessage%28C%29) indicates, return `false` if the overload limit is reached.

Hope this helps you to get started!

Comment: I created a handler and associated it with the request flow and response flow. I have a query, since this handler will be invoked by number of threads simultaneously, do we need to take care of synchronization while incrementing or decrementing the counter value? Also let me know how Axis handles multiple simultaneous requests?

Comment: That's a good question to which I don't know the exact answer. However, since it is very easy to use the atomic classes ([AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) for example), I would suggest you just use one of them.

Comment: Also, those atomic classes are a much better choice in terms of efficiency and error-proneness compared to synchronization (with the `synchronized` keyword).

Comment: The AtomicInteger is introduced from java 1.5 onwards, but our App is running on Java 1.4, So is there any alternate for AtomicInteger in Java 1.4 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, these atomic classes rely on hardware features, meaning you can't just replace them with some library. However, in your case I would argue that a simple `volatile` variable might be enough as well. You will have a race condition in there, but since the arrival of messages is non-deterministic anyway, counting or missing one should not be a big problem.